# SQL Server: Importing database from .mdf?

Tags: sql-server, database, import, mdf, ssms

I have an .mdf file on my local box.

I have SQL Server 2008 Express and SQL Management Studio 2008 Express installed on my local box.

How in the world do I import this .mdf file as a new database into my SQL Server?

This seems like a ridiculously common task that must be performed thousands of times a day across the globe, and I cannot figure out how to do it in Management Studio Express.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

See: [How to: Attach a Database File to SQL Server Express](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165673.aspx)

Login to the database via sqlcmd:

```
sqlcmd -S Server\Instance
```

And then issue the commands:

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE DATABASE [database_name] ON 
( FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data\<database name>.mdf' ),
( FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data\<database name>.ldf' )
 FOR ATTACH ;
GO
```

Comment: And, though it's linked to (indirectly) from that article, here's how to do it [in SSMS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190209.aspx).

Answer (score 36):

Open SQL Management Studio Express and log in to the server to which you want to attach the database. In the 'Object Explorer' window, right-click on the 'Databases' folder and select 'Attach...' The 'Attach Databases' window will open; inside that window click 'Add...' and then navigate to your .MDF file and click 'OK'. Click 'OK' once more to finish attaching the database and you are done. The database should be available for use.
best regards :)

Comment: Like daniele3004 said:
very important, the .mdf file must be located in C:......\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA

Comment: @call-me either that, or the folder that the MDF is in needs to have write permission for the SQL Server user account.

Comment: Aside from having permissions to access the folder and mdf file, I just clicked the missing ldf file in the list (it said something like: file not found) and then clicked Remove, to remove it from the list. Then attach process just worked.

Answer (score 18):

To perform this operation see the next images:

[image]

and next step is add *.mdf file,

**very important, the .mdf file must be located in C:......\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA**

[image]

Now remove the log file

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Apart from steps mentioned in posted answers by @daniele3004 above, I had to open SSMS as Administrator otherwise it was showing Primary file is read only error.

Go to Start Menu , navigate to SSMS link , right click on the SSMS link , select **Run As Administrator**. Then perform the above steps.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have an LDF file then:

1) put the MDF in the `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\`

2) In ssms, go to `Databases -> Attach` and add the MDF file. It will not let you add it this way but it will tell you the database name contained within.

3) Make sure the user you are running ssms.exe as has acccess to this MDF file.

4) Now that you know the DbName, run

```
EXEC sp_attach_single_file_db @dbname = 'DbName', 
@physname = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\yourfile.mdf';
```

Reference: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12089/attaching-mdf-without-ldf

Answer (score 1):

When hosting MS SQL in docker like:

```
version: '3.4'    
services:
  sqlserver:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
    container_name: sqlserver
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - SA_PASSWORD=Samle123$
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    volumes:
      - S:\Database\data:/var/opt/mssql/data
```

it's enough to:

- add **mdf** and **ldf**(option) files to *data* folder (there: *S:\Database\data*)
- in SSMS **Attach** database and selecting copied mdf file.